# GLM Vector Mathematics

Tags: opengl, vector, glsl, physics, glm-math

I have a cube rendered on the screen which represents a car (or similar).

[image: cube]

Using Projection/Model matrices and Glm I am able to move it back and fourth along the axes and rotate it left or right.

I'm having trouble with the vector mathematics to make the cube move forwards no matter which direction it's current orientation is. (ie. if I would like, if it's rotated right 30degrees, when it's move forwards, it travels along the 30degree angle on a new axes).

I hope I've explained that correctly.

This is what I've managed to do so far in terms of using glm to move the cube:

```
glm::vec3 vel; //velocity vector

void renderMovingCube(){

    glUseProgram(movingCubeShader.handle());
    GLuint matrixLoc4MovingCube = glGetUniformLocation(movingCubeShader.handle(), "ProjectionMatrix");  
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc4MovingCube, 1, GL_FALSE, &ProjectionMatrix[0][0]);

        glm::mat4 viewMatrixMovingCube;
        viewMatrixMovingCube = glm::lookAt(camOrigin, camLookingAt, camNormalXYZ);

        vel.x = cos(rotX); vel.y=sin(rotX);
        vel*=moveCube;

        //move cube 
        ModelViewMatrix = glm::translate(viewMatrixMovingCube,globalPos*vel);

        //bring ground and cube to bottom of screen
        ModelViewMatrix = glm::translate(ModelViewMatrix,  glm::vec3(0,-48,0));
        ModelViewMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelViewMatrix, rotX, glm::vec3(0,1,0));     //manually turn

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(movingCubeShader.handle(), "ModelViewMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelViewMatrix[0][0]); //pass matrix to shader
    movingCube.render();        //draw
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

keyboard input:

```
void keyboard()
{
    char BACKWARD  = keys['S']; char FORWARD   = keys['W'];
    char ROT_LEFT  = keys['A']; char ROT_RIGHT = keys['D'];

    if (FORWARD) //W - move forwards
    {
        globalPos += vel;
        //globalPos.z -= moveCube;
        BACKWARD = false;  
    }
    if (BACKWARD)//S - move backwards
    {
        globalPos.z += moveCube;
        FORWARD = false;  
    }
    if (ROT_LEFT)//A - turn left
    {
        rotX +=0.01f;
        ROT_LEFT = false;  
    }
    if (ROT_RIGHT)//D - turn right
    {
        rotX -=0.01f;
        ROT_RIGHT = false; 
    }
```

Where am I going wrong with my vectors? I would like change the direction of the cube (which it does) but then move forwards in that direction.

Comment: Debug your program by monitoring the value of `vel`  in both renderMovingCube and in keyboard.

Comment: Can you describe where the car does move?

Comment: @bwroga Of course, sorry I should of included this.
Basically the car(cube), upon a key press, moves forwards by `moveCube` which is `0.01f` and moves along the `z-axis` (positive set to go away from the camera). It moves backwards which is the opposite of forwards and moves backwards in the negative direction on the `z-axis` (towards the camera). Left and right just rotate the cube on the spot (as seen in the image, having been rotated about 30degrees to the right)... Now I would like it to move forwards the way it is facing... But I can not achieve this... Thanks.

Comment: So right now, the cube always moves along the z-axis, even if it is rotated?

Comment: @bwroga Yes, it does at the moment...